# how can I remove the GUI from RASPBIAN STRETCH WITH DESKTOP?

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-3, gui

I don't want the GUI because my microSD size. I'm just happy with a command-line access. especially now that I downloaded some of the python packages I want to use. Now I only want the command-line access. I have Raspberry PI 3 Model B.

Comment: It is probably easier to burn a new SD card with Raspnian Lite and reinstall your Python packages.

Comment: I tried already but I couldn't download and install the packages I want on Rasbian Lite. and when I tried it with raspbian stretch it worked, but now I don't want the gui anymore.

Comment: If storage space is your biggest concern, you can try manually removing packages, but you'll never get it as compact as the lite versions. You can easily burn a new lite image, then install your python packages from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

The "GUI" i.e. Xorg Display Server, PIXEL desktop environment, Openbox Window Manager and LightDM Login Manager actually takes little space.

Un-installing is possible, however, I suggest you just get rid of the space hogs; Wolfram, Mathematica, Scratch.